# Doctrine many to many using join table and ArrayCollection::map

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have entities "User" and "Agency".  There is a many-to-many relationship between these, but since there are data on the joins between the two, both entities have a OneToMany relationship to a join entity.

So far so good.  However, I have a possibly slightly unusual use case in that my joins need to persist after a User is deleted.  This is because some other data about the deleted user stays on elsewhere, and it's necessary to know about the Agency entities that a User was associated with.

I was using the following method on the Agency entity to fetch Users:

```
public function getLinkedUsers(){
    return $this->userJoins->map(function(UserJoin $join){
        return $join->getUser();
    });
}
```

(where userJoins is an ArrayCollection containing the join entity)

This works great except for when there are joins that do not relate to an existing User record.  When that happens, once I start to iterate through the results and calling methods on them, I get the error:

> Entity of type 'MyApp\Entity\User' for IDs id(10036) was
>   not found

...I can see that this is when Doctrine lazy-loads the actual entity, as before this it is just using proxies.

How to amend my method `getLinkedUsers()` to only return joins that have a corresponding User record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a solution.

In the ManyToOne defintion on the join entity, specifying fetch="EAGER"

```
/**
 * @var User
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="userJoins", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id")
 */
private $user;
```

And back in the Agency entity, my amended method:

```
public function getLinkedUsers(){
    $joinsWithRealUsers = $this->userJoins->filter(function(UserJoin $join){
        return $join->getUser();
    });
    return $joinsWithRealUsers->map(function(UserJoin $join){
        return $join->getUser();
    });
}
```

If anyone wants to tell me a better way of doing this they are welcome, but it works for me.